# put css styles into header section of the page cakePHP

Tags: php, css, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a quick question here. Let say I have a view file `myView.ctp` in cakePHP and inside my view I have some javascript (which I have there for a reason). I know I can tell cake to put my javascript code into the header section of my page by using the [scriptStart()](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1605/scriptStart) and [scriptEnd()](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1606/scriptEnd) blocks like:

```
<?php $html->scriptStart(array('inline' => false)); ?>

// My script code goes here...

<?php $html->scriptEnd(); ?>
```

The `array('inline' => false)`  is what actually tells cake to put my script in the header. Now my question is this: How do I achieve the same thing for css codes (WITHOUT putting my css codes into an external file)? This techniques seem to only work for javascript codes.

Thank you

Comment: Styles *always* belong into the head. Maybe you can try [`style()`](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1440/style) and if not fitting search the docs, e.g. [`css()`](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1437/css) then hacking cakePHP to add the functionality you need.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this article when I was looking to do the same thing.  Turns out there is now (as of Cake 2.1) a slightly more modern way of accomplishing this using view blocks.  To wit:

```
$styleTag = $this->Html->tag('style', $yourCSS);
// adds your stuff to the "css" block which is injected via "fetch" in
// the head section from the view's layout
$this->append('css', $styleTag);
```

P.S. Would be nice if there was a HtmlHelper::tag() equivalent for style blocks instead of merely the content, just for cleanliness.  Oh well.

Answer (score -1):

```
$css = $this->Html->tag('style', '/* my css */');
$view =& ClassRegistry::getObject('view');
$view->addScript($css);
```

The `addScript()` function on the view will append your script to the `$scripts_for_layout` var.

Edit: Comment reiterated something important I missed so I revised the answer.

Comment: @Dave Whoops totally missed that. Revised the answer.

Comment: Still missed the point - he wants to be able to write the style code in his view, but have it populate in his header (layout) file.

Comment: Not able to test, but removed my downvote now, as it appears your answer is on track :)